# Scroll to next image .onkeydown right arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to make it so the image slideshows on my website can be controlled by the left & right arrows. Right now the images scroll by clicking on them. Check out what I have so far here: www.p5js.khom.us

**jquery/js:**

//Here is the code I've been trying to use for the arrows

```
function changeImage(dir) {
    var img = document.getElementById("poop");
    img.src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(img.src) + (dir || 1)] || imgs[dir ? imgs.length - 1 : 0];
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        changeImage(-1) //left <- show Prev image
    } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        // right -> show next image
        changeImage()
    }
}
```

//Accordion Menu and Slideshow

```
var $i = 1, length_img;

$(document).ready(function() {

$('[data-accordion]').accordion({ 'transitionSpeed': 400 });

$('.slide-link').click(function() {
 console.log('YES!');
var id = $(this).data('slide-id');
var $img = $('img[data-slide-id='+id+']');
if ($img.hasClass('current-slide')) return;
var $currentSlide = $('.current-slide');
 $currentSlide.fadeOut();
 $currentSlide.removeClass('current-slide');
 $img.addClass('current-slide');
 $img.fadeIn();
});


$('.slideshow img:last-child').addClass('last');
$('.slideshow').each(function(){
    length_img = $(this).children('img').length;
    $(this).next('.counter').children('p').html( '<span class="number">' + $i + '</span>' + ' of ' + length_img);

  });

$('.slideshow').children('img').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();                                

    $('.slideshow img').removeClass('current-slide');
    length_img = $(this).parent('div').children('img').length;

    if($(this).hasClass('last')){
        $i = 0
        $(this).parent('div').children('img:first').addClass('current-slide').fadeIn();
        $(this).parent('div').next('.counter').children('p').html( '<span class="number">' + ($i+1) + '</span>' + ' of ' + length_img);
    }else{
        $i = $(this).parent('div').next('.counter').children('p').children('span').text();
        $i = parseInt($i);
        console.log($i+1)
        $(this).next('img').fadeIn().addClass('current-slide');
        $(this).parent('div').next('.counter').children('p').html( '<span class="number">' + ($i+1) + '</span>' + ' of ' + length_img);
    }        
});    

$('#navigation').localScroll({
   target:'#scrollable'
});
```

});

**html:**

```
<div class="content">

            <span id="id-01"></span>

                <div class="slideshow">

                    <img class="image image-tall" data-slide-id="1" src="images/apple9.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;" onclick="changeImage()"/>

                    <img class="image image-tall" src="images/apple.gif" alt="image" style="display:none;"/>

                    <img class="image image-logo" src="images/apple11.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;"/>

                </div>

            <div class="counter"><p></p></div>

            <div class="image-number">01</div>

        </div>

        <div class="content">

            <span id="id-02"></span>

                <div class="slideshow">

                    <img class="image image-wide" data-slide-id="2" src="images/apple1.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;"/>

                    <img class="image image-wide" src="images/apple2.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;"/>

                    <img class="image image-wide" src="images/apple3.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;"/>

                </div>

            <div class="counter"><p></p></div>

            <div class="image-number">01</div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Aside from the reference to the non-existent "poop" id I mentioned earlier, "localScroll" is not a function, and an error is thrown in the console when your page is loaded. It looks like maybe you were trying to make use of a jQuery plugin that you aren't actually sourcing perhaps? JQuery itself defines no localScroll function.

Comment: .localScroll isn't part of the problem though

Comment: Also the sketch.js file you are sourcing doesn't have a "}" closing the setup function, which is also throwing a syntax error.